# Unable to create ephemeral instances after enabling Ceph

Tags: openstack, ceph, cinder

Openstack Rocky running on three nodes, ssds as root disks, jbod's for Ceph. Ceph is running on the same nodes as OpenStack.

Before configuring Ceph, all the instances created were ephemeral (as expected ) and I was able to see the disk in /var/lib/nova/instances  and play with it.

After I configure and enable the Ceph and NFS backends in Cinder, I'm unable to create ephemeral instances, all go to ceph-as-block-storage or NFS (depending on the volume created).

If i create a flavor with 10G root and 10G ephemeral, get "/" as 10G on ceph and "/mnt" as 10G on ephemeral, but I can't get the root partition to be ephemeral.

In cinder.conf I have the order like this:

enabled_backends = ceph,nfs

Any ideas on how to enable ephemeral disks again ?

Comment: How are you creating these VMs? Horizon? CLI?

Comment: @eandersson : mostly from horizon. If I create a instance and go via instances -> new-instance -> boot from image -> select image, etc... it is spawned on the NFS backed (but previously to configure NFS backend, the nova service handled the storage and spawned the instance in /var/lib/nova/instances) If I go via Volumes -> new volume -> from image, and then launch the instance from that volume, it goes on ceph storage. I've noticed that I can do ephemeral storage only if I put ephemeral disk quota on the flavor - but that's going to /mnt , not to /

Comment: Under horizon, are you sure "Create New Volume" isn't selected under the Source tab when creating VMs? Because before you configured Ceph, it was probably defaulting to No, that might have changed after you configured Cinder.

Answer (score 0):

Ephemeral disks on instances depends of nova, even though there are a kind of volume, the instances using ephemeral disk are called nova boot also.

Ephemeral disks in real world are bonded to the compute node, because they run locally [1], but is not common on production environments to do that because you will not achieve HA and you can crash the compute node if you use all the space in the node, if you have a ceph storage backend you can use a specific pool for that purpose, I strongly recommend you to check this guide [2], in specific the part to configure libvirt on the ephemeral client secret [3].

Cheers.

[1] https://docs.openstack.org/ha-guide/storage-ha-backend.html

[2] http://docs.ceph.com/docs/master/rbd/rbd-openstack/

[3] http://docs.ceph.com/docs/master/rbd/rbd-openstack/#setup-ceph-client-authentication